# How to change the value of the textbox?

Tags: javascript

I am dong exercise of currency converter.If any of the currency code buttons is clicked, the names of the corresponding country and currency will be displayed. And the amount of HKD for 1 unit (the default value) of local currency will be listed. But it is not working by using **textContent** method.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>

</head>
<body>
<form name='Cuurency Converter' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='3'align='center'>
        <table border='1'align='center'>
    <tr>
        <th colspan='6' align='center'><font size='6'><b>Currency Converter</b></font></th>
     </tr>
         <tr>
         <td align=''center><input type='button' value='USD' id='USD' size='6' onclick='funUSD()'/> </td>    <!-- Function will be called once when the button is clicked. -->
      <td align=''center><input type='button' value='GBP' id='GBP'size='6' onclick='funGBP()'/> </td>
      <td align=''center><input type='button' value='AUD' id='AUD' size='6'onclick='funAUD()'/> </td>
      <td align=''center><input type='button' value='EUR' id='EUR'size='6' onclick='funEUR()'/> </td>
      <td align=''center><input type='button' value='CAD' id='CAD' size='6'onclick='funCAD()'/> </td>
      <td align=''center><input type='button' value='JPY' id='JPY' size='6'onclick='funJPY()'/> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td align=''center><input type='button' value='CNY' id='USD' size='6' onclick='funCNY()'/> </td>    <!-- Function will be called once when the button is clicked. -->
      <td align=''center><input type='button' value='THB' id='GBP'size='6' onclick='funTHB()'/> </td>
      <td align=''center><input type='button' value='NZD' id='AUD' size='6'onclick='funNZD()'/> </td>
      <td align=''center><input type='button' value='CHF' id='EUR'size='6' onclick='funCHF()'/> </td>
      <td align=''center><input type='button' value='SGD' id='CAD' size='6'onclick='funSGD()'/> </td>
      <td align=''center><input type='reset' value='Reset' /> </td>                                     <!-- all context inside of texboxs will be cleared when it is invoked. -->
        </tr>
     <tr>
     <th colspan='6'>Country:<input type='text' id='Country' size='7'/>Cuurrency:<input type='text' id='Currency' size='7'/>
     </th>
     </tr>
      <tr>
     <th colspan='2'>Local<input type='text' size='7'id='localAmount'/></th>
     <th colspan='2'><input type='button' id='equals'value='equals'/></th>
     <th colspan='2'>HKD<input type='text' size='7'id='hkd'/></th>
     </th>
     </tr>
    </tr>
  </table>
        </form>

  <script>
var _textBox1,_textBox2,_textBox3,_textBox4;
      function funUSD(){
   document.getElementsById('Country').textContent='USA'
  
   
   }                              //The name of corresponding countries and currency will be displayed 
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please see [mcve]. "It is not working" might seem like a clear statement to you, because you've _seen_ your code not working, but we have no idea what it means. Please describe exactly how your code is not working. Also, please cut down your large code block to the smallest amount that shows the problem; we don't need to see your whole webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the value with `.value = "__"` for `<input>`.  It's better to use a function accepting the country as a variable, though, since you will only need to write the function once for all countries.  See my working code below.  It uses the country field of each element, meaning I was able to use the same onClick for every country.  There are even more efficient ways outside the scope of this question.

```html
<!doctype html>


<script>
   function funCountry(country) {
      document.getElementById("Country").value = country;
   }
</script>
<html>
   <body>
      <form name='Cuurency Converter' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='3'align='center'>
         <table border='1'align='center'>
            <tr>
               <th colspan='6' align='center'><font size='6'><b>Currency Converter</b></font></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td align=''center><input type='button' value='USD' id='USD' size='6' onclick='funCountry(value)'/> </td>    <!-- Function will be called once when the button is clicked. -->
               <td align=''center><input type='button' value='GBP' id='GBP'size='6' onclick='funCountry(value)'/> </td>
               <td align=''center><input type='button' value='AUD' id='AUD' size='6'onclick='funCountry(value)'/> </td>
               <td align=''center><input type='button' value='EUR' id='EUR'size='6' onclick='funCountry(value)'/> </td>
               <td align=''center><input type='button' value='CAD' id='CAD' size='6'onclick='funCountry(value)'/> </td>
               <td align=''center><input type='button' value='JPY' id='JPY' size='6'onclick='funCountry(value)'/> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td align=''center><input type='button' value='CNY' id='USD' size='6' onclick='funCountry(value)'/> </td>    <!-- Function will be called once when the button is clicked. -->
               <td align=''center><input type='button' value='THB' id='GBP'size='6' onclick='funCountry(value)'/> </td>
               <td align=''center><input type='button' value='NZD' id='AUD' size='6'onclick='funCountry(value)'/> </td>
               <td align=''center><input type='button' value='CHF' id='EUR'size='6' onclick='funCountry(value)'/> </td>
               <td align=''center><input type='button' value='SGD' id='CAD' size='6'onclick='funCountry(value)'/> </td>
               <td align=''center><input type='reset' value='Reset' /> </td>                                     <!-- all context inside of texboxs will be cleared when it is invoked. -->
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <th colspan='6'>Country:<input type='text' id='Country' size='7'/>Cuurrency:<input type='text' id='Currency' size='7'/>
               </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <th colspan='2'>Local<input type='text' size='7'id='localAmount'/></th>
               <th colspan='2'><input type='button' id='equals'value='equals'/></th>
               <th colspan='2'>HKD<input type='text' size='7'id='hkd'/></th>
            </tr>
         </table>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I know what you mean.So if i want to change the content of non-input type elements such as <p> <h1> , I should use textContent or innerHtml method. But if those are input type whatever they are button or textbox that i should use .value='xxxx'. right?

Comment: Exactly!  Here's some examples, even though it sounds like you don't need them :)  https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_html.asp https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_intro_inner_html

Answer (score -1):

It's `document.getElementById()` and not `document.getElementsById()`.

Check the spelling of the function. (Id is unique, so don't have **s** in `getElementsById`)

Comment: There were other problems this does not address, including the way they set the value of the element found.

Comment: Fair enough, but if you don't have it syntactically correct, the logic doesn't matter.

Comment: Yes, but if you're going to answer, you should provide a full answer.  Comments are where you put small syntactic mistakes, especially if the question has already been answered with a working solution.

Comment: I was trying to help the OP with his "exercise" rather than do it for him.  For what it's worth, your answer wasn't visible to me when I clicked the "Post Your Answer" button.